# Login user session in functional Test. Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, session, cookies, playframework-1.x

I need to login the user, so I can access methods that return data that I need to test.

I am able to do a login, but only with Http.Request like this.

```
    Map<String, String> loginUserParamsCompany5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    loginUserParamsCompany5.put("username", "user@Company.com");
    loginUserParamsCompany5.put("password", "userPassword");
    Http.Response loginResponse = POST("/login", loginUserParamsCompany5);
```

After this the user is logged out.

```
String session = Scope.Session.current().get("logged");
```

This will return  null.

I want a way to keep the user logged in, or to do the login some other way, so I can have access to the method I need.